# How to detect IE "Update Versions"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

After IE was updated to Update Versions 11.0.35, the timings of "keydown" event and DOM mutation were changed when Hangul is edited in content editable blocks.

How can I detect IE Update Versions in Javascript?

(IE ScriptEngineMajor/Minor/BuildVersion functions are not useful because it is different even in case of same "Update Versions")

[Internet Explorer Information (Korean ver.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RErcD.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Windows Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
    return rv;
}

function checkIEVersion() {
    var msg = "You're not using Windows Internet Explorer.";
    var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();
    if (ver > -1) {
        console.log(ver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Major version is not helpful in my case. The Hangul event change is occured in Update Version 11.0.35, but it is not occured in 11.0.34. (Please see the linked picture on above question.)

Comment: UserAgent and AppVersion strings are as follows. ["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko"], ["5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko"]